# How to exit shell when the script contains restarting a new instance?

Tags: powershell, exit

At the beginning of my script, I add a piece of code to make sure the shell [run with full admin privileges](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/running-script-with-full-privileges):

```
# Running with full admin privileges
param([switch]$Elevated)

function Test-Admin {
    $currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
    $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}

if ((Test-Admin) -eq $false)  {
    if ($elevated) {
        # tried to elevate, did not work, aborting
    } else {
        Start-Process pwsh -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -noexit -file "{0}" -elevated' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition))
    }
    exit
}

# Other stuff below...
```

After that is a normal script (the `Other stuff below` section). The problem is, I want to automatically close the shell window after the script is done. Before I add the full privilege code, putting `exit` in the bottom of the script works fine, but not now anymore. I don't understand why, because everything else in this section works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally scripts auto exit at the end.
Try to omit `-noexit` parameter from argumentlist and delete `exit` at the bottom of the script.
For me, there is no sense to call a script with `-noexit` and put `exit` at the end of it. Without these all will automagically work.

If you want to examine what is going on during script writing, you can put eg. a `timeout /t 90` command at the end, so you get 90 seconds to examine output before it auto closes.